# Admob ad unit id big confusion

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, publisher

I have a unity3d plugin for integrating admob ads. Its asking for ad unit id in this format "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/NNNNNNNNNN" but the publisher id of any given app in my admob account is in this format "a15854eg4d5rh64". What is my ad unit id? I'm totally confused and search all over the search engines without any answers. I'm literally smashing my head and search for a working solution since 6 hours straight.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

If your adUnit ids are of the form 'a15854eg4d5rh64' then it sounds like you are still using the legacy Admob dashboard. It may still be rolling out in some countries (such as India).

If that is the case then that **is** your AdUnitId.